# Product Price disappeared from frontend magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, price

Products Prices does not show up on my magneto 2.3 web frontend. https://prnt.sc/p9mu83
Mapping is set to No in stores->configuration->sales->sales.https://prnt.sc/p9mtre
What is the issue.
Prices suddenly got disappeared.

Comment: try check style.

Comment: @MichaelHa What style.........?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem, I think maybe the wrong style of price.

Comment: @MichaelHa Everything was working fine earlier. This problem arises suddenly

Comment: I find a report https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17897

Comment: share website link here

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad https://ihouzit.com

Comment: Have you run price indexer & try to clear your cache ?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Yes, my indexing is running on cron properly. DId u try inspecting the site and check. i can guess my third party module creating problme.

Comment: yes I check in your custom theme special price template price is not rendering.

Comment: Are you facing this issue at your local environment as well ?

Comment: Also once try to run indexing manually & clear cache as after that

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Its working fine on my staging environment

Comment: which magento2 version it is ?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Its magento 2.3.0

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands in same sequence in your base folder where M2.3 installed:

```
    sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
    php bin/magento indexer:reindex
    php bin/magento cache:flush
    php  -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
    sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
```

Reload Home page, IF still issue not resolved then disable custom modules one by one and try to grab the culprit for fix.

Comment: If i disabled the module and enable it again, i hope data wont vanish. I will get all my configurations and data from databases right?

Comment: Have you first run above commands one by one ?

Comment: @Hassan...Yes done that